# Bijection: tree-like lists - natural numbers

Tags: code-golf, encoding

We define a *tree-like list*, or *trist* for short, as the empty list or a list containing only previously constructed trists.

The *natural numbers* can either include 0 or not, according to your preference.

The task is to create a pair of functions or complete programs `f` and `g` (they don't have to be named like this or even named at all) that implement a bijection between trists and the natural numbers.  In other words:

- `f` must be able to turn any trist into a natural number
- `g` must be able to turn any natural number into a trist
- `f(g(n))` must equal `n` for any natural number `n`
- `g(f(l))` must be equivalent to `l` for any trist `l`

You can assume that all arguments and results fit in the usual numeric type for your language.
Alternatively, instead of the numeric type you could represent a natural number as a list of binary digits, either consistently little- or consistently big-endian.

The shortest solution per language wins. If your functions are recursive, you [must name them](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13225/byte-count-for-named-recursive-lambda-expressions-in-c-answers). If your language requires a statement separator or a newline between the two functions/programs, you *don't* have to count it.

This is a sample algorithm in Python3 (you are free to implement the bijection in any way you like):

```
def f(x):
    r = 0
    for y in x:
        r = (2 * r + 1) * 2**f(y)
    return r

def g(n):
    r = []
    while n:
        m = 0
        while n % 2 == 0:
            n //= 2
            m += 1
        n //= 2
        r = [g(m)] + r
    return r

tests = [
    [],
    [[]],
    [[],[]],
    [[[]],[],[[[]],[]]],
    [[[[[]]]]],
]
for l in tests: print(g(f(l)) == l)

for n in range(20): print(f(g(n)) == n)
```

It uses the following representation:

\$
\begin{array}{|l}
f([~])=0\\
f([a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}])=\overline{
1\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{f(a_0)\\\text{zeroes}}~
1\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{f(a_1)\\\text{zeroes}}~
\ldots~
1\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{f(a_{n-1})\\\text{zeroes}}}
{}_{(2)}
\end{array}
\$

Challenge inspired by @LeakyNun's [question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45917001#45917001) in chat.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95035/36398)

Comment: The similarity to [Decode the Void](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119994/decode-the-void) is striking. Duplicate indeed, and I suck at searching PPCG.

Comment: PPCG sucks at being searched.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>118</s> <s>114</s> <s>109</s> <s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>97</s> 94 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x>[]and f(x[:-1])*2+1<<f(x[-1])
g=lambda n:[g(len(w))for w in bin(n).split('1')[1:]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7NDoIwDL7vKXpjVTSO4yK@yLLDCDBJZiGwBHz6SREjvfT7ab6vwzs@eypSasvgXlXtYNHLw1hHNbRyMfqiLJ6Ks7rfmTIT/ndK2ngZGpIzYtuPMENHUHUkCa/TELooM5WhUdraFJspTlCCEbCOsfl3G/tH@YEwZGUHB4OVjVvBnYE7t3ANw9hRBC9bGRChLCEIsWn7AhfCavr1v80m4ATihNGRb2RxQ0wf)

Same encoding as the example...

Comment: @Lynn, it seems i can remove `n and` and it still works

Comment: @TFeld I'm afraid [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12680/multiple-functions-without-leading-trailing-mandatory-parts#13233) implies that `f=` and `g=` should be counted. Sorry for the confusion. You can still omit the newline, as I intended the byte count to be the sum of two separate functions/programs.

Comment: @ngn, No problem, I've counted them in my counts already (and omitted the newline)